# Invalid Syntax (near date)

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

i found this code in stackoverflow. suits my requirements. i'm using an mysql db that consists of id, date, gender, name and surname. i have made few changes to the code so that i can obtain the date and other info between the start date and the end date.

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector
import command
import datetime

def findarbs(startdate, enddate):
      con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='root', 
host='localhost',port='3306',database='testdb')
      cur = con.cursor()
      command = ("SELECT DISTINCT id, date FROM babyrop", WHERE 'date1' 
      > ('%s') AND 'date2' < ('%s'), ORDER BY date asc % (startdate, 
enddate))
print ('command')
cursor.execute(command)
result = cur.fetchone()
print (result)
while result is not None:
print (result[1])
result = cursor.fetchone()
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select id, date weight from babyrop')

data = cursor.fetchall()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

when i tried executing it i'm getting an error "invalid syntax" near date. let me know what corrections to are required.

Comment: You are completely messing up the `command` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are terminating the string way too early. You also have invalid commas in the query.

   ```
   command = ("SELECT DISTINCT id, date FROM babyrop", WHERE 'date1' 
         > ('%s') AND 'date2' < ('%s'), ORDER BY date asc % (startdate, 
   enddate))
   ```

   "should" be

   ```
       command = ("SELECT DISTINCT id, date FROM babyrop WHERE 'date1' 
     > ('%s') AND 'date2' < ('%s') ORDER BY date asc" % (startdate, 
   enddate))
   ```
2. I wrote "should" because you should **not** use string concatenation in queries since it exposes your code to SQL injection. You should use parametrized queries instead. It also recommended to use triple quotes for query strings so they can be broken apart nicely:

   ```
       command = """SELECT DISTINCT id, date
                    FROM babyrop
                    WHERE 'date1' > ('%s') AND 'date2' < ('%s')
                    ORDER BY date asc"""

       cursor.execute(command, (startdate, enddate))
   ```

   Also, I'm pretty sure that you don't need the single quotes (`'`) around the columns names and the placeholders in the `where` clause but that might be a MySQL thing.

Comment: hey, i tried doing the changes you mentioned, but getting the following error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shalini/Desktop/wenzins/13th nov/pyhton+mysql between.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor.execute(command,(startdate, enddate))
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined

Comment: You used `cursor` in your code that I copy pasted, but it should be `cur` .

Comment: i replaced cursor with cur and i'm getting the following error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shalini\Desktop\wenzins\13th nov\pyhton+mysql between.py", line 12, in <module>
    cur.execute(command)
NameError: name 'cur' is not defined

Comment: @shalinikrishna Your code is probably messed up. It'd be best if you open a new question with your *actual*, *current* code.

Comment: ya. sure. thnk you